# Is there a step in Pentaho Spoon to use a transformation as inner query?

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, inner-query

[Transformation example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziA5y.png)

Is there a way for me to use a transformation like this to use as an inner query in 'table input 4' like using 'insert data from the step' or 'execute sql script'? If not, is my only option using the whole query in the table input step?

Comment: ?? What is your question? The Table input step allows you to pass the query to execute as Insert data from step, each column you pass will be an argument in your query. From your example screenshot you seem to know how the "Insert data from step" works, so what is your question?

Comment: I want to use CASE clauses in 'Table Input 4' using the output I get by using the steps before that, but when I use any query in 'Table Input 4' I get an error at the end of the process. I cannot send the error because it works so slow, but I will send that as soon as possible.

Comment: Couldn't get field info from [SELECT d_kayitno FROM ?] offending row : 'All column names(Some numbers)' Error setting value #2 [Integer(15)] on prepared statement Invalid column index Is the error I get and I don't know how to fix it at all.

Comment: You must be very careful when you use a ? and replace it with a value from the previous step. If you have one ? in your SQL, make sure only one column comes as an input to the Table Input step. If you input two columns, it will fail. Use select values before Table Input to select only one column.

Comment: But I need to use the whole table which includes all the variables(sometimes around 750-800). What can I do to fix that issue?

Comment: It's going to be impossible to help you out without reproducible examples. My impression is that if your code is so complicated, possibly instead of cramming all the difficulties into one select statement you could use a more simple select, or different transformations to get different selects, and add different steps after the selects using metadata injections, and a final transformation to unify the different results of the previous transformations.